# Is there a way to get pricing details per resource in Azure through an API call?

Tags: azure, rest, api

I need to see how much money is spent on each resource. I want to get that information through an API call, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at Consumption API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/) especially Usage Details - List operation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list).